# How to change an incorrect Mac file's Kind

Tags: sqlite, file-association

I have several SQLITE files all of which have Kind set correctly to Document except for one which is Kind = Unix Executable file.  It still loads and runs fine. I'd like to clean this up but can't find a way to change Kind for this file to Document.

Anybody know why Kind would have been set incorrectly in the first place and how to change it to the correct value?  I've searched here and on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an extension (possibly hidden) set on the file? I think that 'Documents' are merely files without extensions. I'd try File>Get Info on it (via Finder) and checking to make sure there isn't a hidden extension in the 'Name & Extension'

Comment: The extension is the same as all the other SQLITE files on my computer, .sqlite.  Yet its Kind is different.

Comment: In that case, I'd try removing the '.sqlite' from the file name, applying the change, then adding it back in. I'm pretty sure that the 'Kind' is inferred only from the extension.

Comment: I've already tried that a couple of times.  Doesn't fix it.  All my SQLITE files have exactly the same extension, except one is described as a UNIX Executable File.  Really weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my php_error.log file. It was "document" and then I foolishly changed the "kind". That mean that the php log wouldn't work and my MAMP server didn't recognise it.

It's still "text document", but to fix the issue I opened up the file in TextEdit, selected "make rich text" under format, saved the file, closed it down, reopened it in TextEdit, selected "make plain text" under format, saved the file and it worked...